# Accessing Related Object Data in AngularFire for Firebase

Tags: angularjs, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to relate a business to another business in my Firebase data and then use AngularFire to ng-repeat through the related businesses. My Firebase data is structured like so:

```
{
  "businesses" : {
    "-KQ1ggyrnYGYL1084Htz" : {
      "name" : "Some Business",
      "cat" : "Food",
      "related" : {
        "-KQ1hFH0qrvKSrymmn9d" : true,
```

In my JS I have the following factory and controller:

```
app.factory("Businesses", ['$firebaseArray', function ($firebaseArray) {
    var stuff = firebase.database().ref().child("businesses");
    var Businesses = $firebaseArray(stuff);
    return Businesses;
}])
```

And my controller:

```
app.controller('businessCtrl', ['$scope','$firebaseArray','Businesses', function ($scope, $firebaseArray, Businesses) {
    $scope.businesses = Businesses;
```

In the HTML I then loop through the "Related" businesses using an ng-repeat like so:

```
<span>Related:</span>

<a ng-repeat="item in businesses.related" ui-sref="shop.item({item: item.link})">
     <div class="chip">
          <img ng-src="{{item.card}}" alt="Contact Person">
               {{item.name}}
     </div>
</a>
```

But I seem unable to access any data such as "name" from my {{item.name}}. What do I need to do to be able to access the data of the referenced business?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I discovered how to do this sometime later. It may have worked the way I was trying, but it's not the recommended approach. For one, denormalization in Firebase is normal. Meaning, instead of placing the related businesses in a sub-object I need to create a new object like so:

```
businesses
    -BusinessKey
related
    -BusinessKey
        -RelatedBusinessKey
```

Then get the data like so:

```
$scope.related = [];
const businessKey = $scope.finalItem.$id;
const rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
const discoverRef = rootRef.child('discover');
const businessRef = rootRef.child('businesses');

function getRelatedContent(key, cb) {
   relatedRef.child(key).on('child_added', snap => {
       let businesRef = businessRef.child(snap.key);
       businesRef.once('value', cb);
   });
}

getRelatedContent(businessKey, snap => {
    var snapVal = snap.val();
        $scope.related.push(snapVal);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the data `item.name` then use `item in businesses` instead of `item in businesses.related`

When using `item in businesses.related` you are getting the data as `item.-KQ1hFH0qrvKSrymmn9d`

Comment: I am using `item in businesses` to get the business initially. But then I want to loop through a handful of businesses related to that business so I used the firebase object key to hopefully reference that business. If I use `item in businesses` again I will get all businesses as opposed to the few I referenced if I'm understanding correctly.